# Upload data from nacl via http

Tags: http, google-nativeclient

Is there a way to upload data from the client nacl code via HTTP?
I know that curl was ported to nacl but it looks the client browser needs to run with --allow-nacl-socket-api argument and this is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you package your NaCl plugin as part of an extension, and request 'socket' permissions in your manifest, you shouldn't need the flag.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket